# Repository not found while pushing

Tags: git

I just created a github repo to push my local git repo to, but upon pushing and entering the password, I'm getting:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/zendevil/humboi.git/' not found
```

pushing with

```
git push origin creations
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Is it a private repo? The url https://github.com/zendevil/humboi.git/ gives a 404 error.

Comment: yes it's private

Answer (score 0):

As I read in a comment from you in another answer, you want to push an **existing** local repository into a **new** remote repository. For that, you must change the *remote-url*.

Check the output from `git remote -v`. It will look like this:

```
origin  https://github.com/zendevil/humboi.git/ (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/zendevil/humboi.git/ (push)
```

But your error message says that this repository no longer exists remotely. I assume, this is still the *remote-url* from the *old* repository. Now you need to change the *remote-url* to the *new* repository.

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<username>/<repo-name.git>
```

After this, you will be able to `git push` your changes into this repository.

Answer (score -2):

After you create a repository, github shows you little tutorial on how to get it locally (either from existing repository or create a new one). You follow those steps and your repo will work.

If that is not the case, there are couple of options like "connection issues" or your repository is not public. In latter case make sure your ssh is set up properly and make sure you are cloning using `ssh://` and not `https://`

Comment: I cannot clone the repo. I have to push an existing repo that already has code and a commit history

Comment: My point about cloning was just to make sure you are doing git operations correctly (thats often not the case). If thats not your issue I would think its issue from second half of my reply, you probably dont have proper permissions to said repository. If its private, it needs to verify your ssh credentials. So you have to have correct private/public pair (with private in your `~/.ssh` and public uploaded on remote (usually you do this on web gui). First try to change remote to `ssh://` and then verify your private/public pair.